# Checking for a non ascii character in SQL Query activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, automation, sqlserver

I have certain records in my DE, where the first name contains '�'. I wish to extract such records. Obviously a like wouldn't work. Is there a way to do this in SQL Query Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue in my instance.

You can see one row is fine but the other row has has special characters as per the below screenshot:

[image]

You can use the below SQL Query :

```
Select [Template Identifier],Country,[Reservation Text],[Booking Text] 
from [Test Dynamic Text]
where [Booking Text] <> CONVERT(varchar, [Booking Text])
```

At the resultant data extension am getting only one row which has the special characters.
Let me know if this helps.

[image]

Comment: Worked... Thanks Naveen!

Comment: You are welcome @smsy31!

Answer (score 3):

You can find those records containing multi-byte characters by converting the First Name field to a single-byte data type and then comparing against the First Name for equality:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName
FROM 
    MyDataExtension
WHERE
    FirstName != cast(FirstName as varchar(1000))
```

If you're specifically interested in locating records that contain the unicode replacement character, '�', then narrow down your comparison to just this one character code:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName
FROM 
    MyDataExtension
WHERE
    CHARINDEX(NCHAR(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,FirstName) > 0
```

Comment: let me try, as my first name also has other valid characters like Æ

Comment: This is not working, it is just returning all the names with special characters

Comment: I'll update to search specifically for the unicode replacement character, "�", if you like.